# Closure templates from multiple soy files

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

I have a template called `templates.soy` and I would like to be able to call a template from a separate file (would like to overwrite that file programmatically from time to time). I can call a template within the same file.  Currently I have:

### templates.soy

```
{namespace plugin.example}

/**
 * Template for the build
 */
{template .anthill}
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    <body>
        <h2>My Form</h2>
        <br />
        {call .form /}  //This works
        {call random.me.moreFields /}  //This throws an error "Attempting to render undefined template 'random.me.moreFields'
    </body>
</html>
{/template}

/**
 * Form info
 */
{template .form}
    //custom html form stuff
{/template}
```

### selectField.soy

```
{namespace random.me}
/**
 * Testing more soy files
 */
{template .moreFields}
   //custom html stuff
{/template}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, I'm a bit surprised you want to generate soy templates programmatically. Soy is a meta-language itself, compiled into JavaScript or java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It's even the best practice to have one file per component or page.

Just [compile all templates simultaneously](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage?compilation).

```
java -jar SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar --srcs templates.soy,selectField.soy
```